# MapRouting ASP.Net MVC4 - Cant generate new URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with my MapRouting. I want to generate new URL's with the name from an array list. I am new with MVC and are trying with the experiense from Web app's. I want to generate new links that dont have Action in it. I just want "Localhost/Chat/" + chatName. Please ask me questions if you dont understand sense im not so good at explaining!

```
        LocalhostHoardeWebService.varShareWS addChatRooms = new LocalhostHoardeWebService.varShareWS();
        Array wsRespnonsAddChatObject = addChatRooms.addAllChatRoomsRoute();



        foreach (string chatNameArray in wsRespnonsAddChatObject)
        {
            string chatName = chatNameArray.ToString();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: chatName,
                url: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Chat", id = chatName  }
           );

        }
```

Comment: You need to specify an action and you do not/should not specify the id - you just pass that as a parameter `url: "Chat/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = "Index" }`

Comment: It still does not work with    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: chatName,
                    url: "Chat/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action ="Index" }
               ); Any idea why?

Comment: Have you got rid of the loop (its just one route definition), and do you have and `public ActionResult Index(string id)` method in `ChatController`? You should also specify a name (say `name: chat`)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, the problem was that i did not understand correctly how MVC works (that you can get an id to the controller depending on what you type in the URL). Many thanks to you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your misunderstanding how routes work. You need to specify a default controller and action method, and in the action method you pass the value of `chatName` to a parameter. you route should look like (one route, no loop). Also make sure this is above the Default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "chat",
  url: "Chat/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Chat", action = Index }
);
```

and in `ChatController`

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
  // id is the value of chatName
}
```

and call it as `/Chat/abc` or `/Chat/xyz`